# Inverse quadratic method only makes one iteration - python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm tryin' to implement this method with python3 but i don't solve the problem. This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import sympy
import numpy as np


x = sympy.symbols('x')

expr = x ** 2 - 2
fx = sympy.lambdify(x, expr, 'numpy')

def quad_inv(f, x0, x1, x2, tol, maxiter):
    fx0 = f(x0)
    fx1 = f(x1)
    fx2 = f(x2)
    x3 = None
    iters = 0
    error = tol + 1
    if np.sign(tol) < 0:
        raise ValueError('La tolerancia debe ser estrictamente positiva.')

    while (error >= tol) & (iters <= maxiter):
        a = fx1 * fx2 / ((fx0 - fx1) * (fx0 - fx2)) * x0
        b = fx0 * fx2 / ((fx1 - fx0) * (fx1 - fx2)) * x1
        c = fx0 * fx1 / ((fx2 - fx0) * (fx2 - fx1)) * x2
        x3 = a + b + c
        x0 = x1
        x1 = x2
        x2 = x3
        error = abs((x3 - x0) * (x3 - x1) * (x3 - x2))
        print(error)
        iters += 1
    return[x3, iters]

 sol = quad_inv(fx, 1., 1.2, 1.6, 0.0001, 300)
    print('La raíz aproximada con el Método Inversa Cuadrática es:\n{0}'.format(sol[0]))
    print('Se han realizado un total de {0} iteraciones.'.format(sol[1]))
```

I only get 1 iteration. I don't find anything about the error cote with this method.

```
La raíz aproximada con el Método Inversa Cuadrática es:
1.4195804195804194
Se han realizado un total de 1 iteraciones.
```

Comment: Since you explicitly set `x2 = x3`, of course the last term `(x3 - x2)` and hence `error` is zero. You shouldn't use the product, anyway, but the sum (of absolute values). You probably also want to update the function values `fx0`, `fx1`, `fx2` at some point...

Comment: Ok I've fixed with your suggestions, but i don't understand about absolute values sum. Can you write it? The error formula is not the product of nodes?

Comment: Taking the product of the differences is not a useful metric of error.  As you originally coded it, one factor was small (zero in fact), so the product can be small without guaranteeing that all three differences are small.

Comment: @Tobal I meant `err = abs(x3-x0)+abs(x3-x1)+abs(x3-x2)` (before you update `x0` etc!), although `err = abs(x3-x2)` would suffice (the older iterates do not contain independent information).